# JQuery JSON to MySql Insert

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json

I have a Captivate training that I am hosting without a LMS but I want to send data from the training. I have written the javascript to establish the variables and post to a php page but I am not able to get the request via post. Thoughts??

Javascript:

```
var currentTime = new Date();
var month = currentTime.getMonth() + 1;
var day = currentTime.getDate();
var year = currentTime.getFullYear();

var myMovie = CaptivateController("Captivate");
//Retrieves the author's name, if available
var cpInfoCourseName = myMovie.query("cpInfoCourseName");
var currentDate = year + "-" + month + "/" + day;
var cpQuizInfoPassFail = myMovie.query("cpQuizInfoPassFail"); //1 = pass; 0 = fail
var cpQuizInfoPointsscored = myMovie.query("cpQuizInfoPointsscored");
var cpQuizInfoQuizPassPercent = myMovie.query("cpQuizInfoQuizPassPercent");
var cpQuizInfoTotalCorrectAnswers = myMovie.query("cpQuizInfoTotalCorrectAnswers");

var jsonData = "{'cpInfoCourseName': cpInfoCourseName, 'currentDate': currentDate, 'cpQuizInfoPassFail': cpQuizInfoPassFail, 'cpQuizInfoPointsscored': cpQuizInfoPointsscored,'cpQuizInfoTotalCorrectAnswers':cpQuizInfoTotalCorrectAnswers}";

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "../../trainingReporting.php",
  dataType:"application/json",
  data: jsonData,
  success: function() {
        //alert("Your training results were saved and sent to your regional office.");
        //location.href = 'http://www.occ-connect.org/seconnect/occTrainings.php';           
    },
  error: function() {
                alert("Your data was not submitted");
    }
});
```

PHP:

```
    if(isset($_POST['data'])){
    $jsonData = $_POST['data'];

    //get region, email and ministry position of user
    $userInfo = mysql_query("SELECT profilevalue_8,profilevalue_9 FROM se_profilevalues WHERE profilevalue_user_id = '".$user->user_info['user_id']."'");

    while($r = mysql_fetch_array($userInfo))
    {
        $region = $r['profilevalue_9'];
        $ministry_position = $r['profilevalue_8'];
    }

    $user_id = $user->user_info['user_id'];
    $user_email = $user->user_info['user_email'];

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO trainingReporting (json,user_email,user_id,region,ministry_position) VALUES ('$jsonData','$user_email','$user_id','$region','$ministry_position')") or die('INSERT FAILED: '. mysql_error());
    echo "success!";

} else {
    echo "error";
}
```

Comment: `jsonData` is not a valid JSON. Write it as a normal object and let jQuery do  the conversion

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `contentType` to your ajax call.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "../../trainingReporting.php",
  dataType:"application/json",
  data: jsonData,
  contentType: "application/json",
  success: function() {...
```

By default jQuery uses `application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8` as the format and you want it to be json.

`dataType` is to specify the format of the data returned by the server.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

with jquery, the data property gets converted to the post data. so you wouldn't use `$_POST['data']` in php, but the column names under your jsonData var. so $_POST['cpInfoCourseName']...etc. Or if you want everything to be under `$_POST['data']`, in javascript you can do something like: `data:{'data':jsonData},` and wrap the js var jsonData in an object literal under the `data` key.

you can also run print_r($_POST) to show all the data in $_POST.